# How to handle node.js errors properly - the standart way

Tags: node.js, error-handling

**For about developer errors that are made by mistake or undefined or something else that can crash the whole app:**

Should I use this:

```
var domain = require('domain');
var d = domain.create();
d.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});

d.run(function() {
  if (someom.sadjaslkd.asdasd=="yes") console.log("Yes");
  // run more other things in the safe area
});
```

Purposely `someom.sadjaslkd.asdasd` is undefined.

OR should I use this:

```
try {
 if (someom.sadjaslkd.asdasd=="yes") console.log("Yes");
 // run more other things in the safe area
} catch(err) {
 // handle the error safely
}
```

**For about operation errors that are made not by mistake but due to client's faults:**

Should I use this:

```
if (somethingWorng) res.status(400).json({status: "400", error: "Some custom error message to the user"});
```

OR maybe I should pass the error like this:

```
if (somethingWorng) throw "Some custom error message to the user";
```

OR maybe

```
if (somethingWorng) throw new Error("Some custom error message to the user");
```

Really there tons of ways to make this work. Is there a quick easy, readable, best practice?